# Thin, Black, Light font style for CSS

Tags: css, fonts

i did include this line in my CSS file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i')
```

Normal Lato Font works fine, but I can't figure how to use 'Black' or 'Light' versions of this Lato Font..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thickness is specified by the font weight number of the Google font (ie 300 for light, 900 for black etc);

Use:

```
.element {
    font-weight:300;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aof10ut2/

Comment: Hi, i did try to use font=weight. but still cannot solve the problem :(